# Script with non-option and option arguments

Tags: bash, getopts

I'm trying to handle both optional and mandatory parameter to my bash script. I have following script:

```
while getopts "a:x:" opt; do
  case $opt in
     a) echo "option a set: $OPTARG" ;;
     x) echo "option x set: $OPTARG" ;;
     \?) echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2; exit 1;;
esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

echo "mandatory argument $1"
echo "mandatory argument2 $2"
```

Everything looks ok when I run my script using following command:

```
./script.sh -a optionA -x optionX mandatory1 mandatory2
```

But when I mix this params:

```
./script.sh mandatory1 mandatory2 -a optionA -x optionX
```

It doesn't... How to make it works for all combination of parameters?

Comment: does different order mean a different thing? if not, I don't see the point of doing this.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath it means totally same thing that's why it should work exactly the same way. And it doesn't.

Comment: there's nothing wrong it. it's a unix (de facto?) standard to start with the flags...

Comment: More concretely, `getopts` only parses options until it sees the first argument that does not start with `-`. The similarly named external program `getopt` implements the more flexible GNU-style argument parsing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate between both kinds of argument, I think.

I think this does what you want, and allows you to use `--` to prevent the following arguments being interpreted as options.

```
mandatory=()
while [ $# -gt 0 ] && [ "$1" != "--" ]; do
  while getopts "a:x:" opt; do
    case $opt in
       a) echo "option a set: $OPTARG" ;;
       x) echo "option x set: $OPTARG" ;;
       \?) echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2; exit 1;;
  esac
  done
  shift $((OPTIND-1))

  while [ $# -gt 0 ] && ! [[ "$1" =~ ^- ]]; do
    mandatory=("${mandatory[@]}" "$1")
    shift
  done
done

if [ "$1" == "--" ]; then
  shift
  mandatory=("${mandatory[@]}" "$@")
fi

echo "mandatory argument ${mandatory[0]}"
echo "mandatory argument2 ${mandatory[1]}"
```

Basically, the idea is to consume all the options with getopt, then consume all the non-options manually, then look for more options with getopt again.

Comment: Nice, but it'd be even better if you handled "--" as an "options end here" delimiter.

Comment: I tested it now and fixed the bugs.

Answer (score -2):

To make it work I had to unset OPTIND after the `shift $((OPTIND-1))`:

```
[...]
shift $((OPTIND-1))
unset OPTIND
[...]
```